# How to import a function that you do not know the names of in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, eval

So, I am trying to import a function, from a specific file, and run it, in a function on a different file. Here is my code:

```
import re

def get_func_names(string):
    temp = re.compile(r"def [a-z]+")
    result = temp.findall(string)
    return [elem[4:] for elem in result]

def test_a_function(val):
    import swift
    g = open('swift.py', 'r')
    g = g.read()
    functions = get_func_names(g)
    k = functions[0]
    k = eval(k(val))
    return k
```

get_func_names uses the re module and pattern matching to get all the names that appear after 'def' in a python document, and only returns the names of the functions. test_a_function imports the python document, opens it, applies get_func_names, and tries to evaluate the first string of a function name using the eval function, but i get an error saying the 'str' object is not callable.

Is there a way to fix my method or another way to do this?

EDIT:

Ok thank you for the answer, but in the end for some reason, it would only work with the importlib module

```
import importlib
import types

def getfuncs(modulename):
    retval = {}
    opened = importlib.import_module(modulename)
    for name in opened.__dict__.keys():
        if isinstance(opened.__dict__[name], types.FunctionType):
            retval[name] = opened.__dict__[name]
    return retval
```

Comment: Huh? Why are you trying to eval anything? Just import your file as a module, and pull what you want out of its dictionary. Look at `__imp__()`.

Comment: Python has a great, robust AST module, too. You can let its parser do the work of finding things in another source file. Trying to use regexes is just completely unnecessary pain and suffering (and buggy, since your regex doesn't know if a `def foo` is inside a multi-line string).

Comment: Places to start: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html; https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: Oh -- also https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__, and/or https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
import types

def getfuncs(modulename):
    retval = {}
    module = __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
    for (name, item) in module.__dict__.iteritems():
        if isinstance(item, types.FunctionType):
            retval[name] = item
    return retval

getfuncs('swift') # returns a dictionary of functions in the swift module
```

If you don't want side effects from evaluation occurring at the module level you could use the AST module to only evaluate function definitions, but this would be considerably more work (and modules written not expecting this behavior would not necessarily function correctly).